# Python - Encoding file using flip cipher

Tags: python, encoding

I'm trying to encode a file using a flip cipher. I've written a program to encode a string and it has worked on normal strings. I wrote another program to read a file, encode it in blocks, then write it to an output file. It works fine for around 1MB, but then I get an error. No matter what key string I use, I get a

```
TypeError: must be string or buffer, not None
```

I've written some error checking into the encoding function itself, and that comes up with an error. Here's my code, if someone could have a look.

The file with functions:

```
class KeyString:
    def genNums(self):
        self.keys = {}
        i = 1
        for letter in self.chars:
            self.keys[letter] = i
            i += 1

    def __init__(self,chars='"LB}+h<=,.T->XcxzCdD*2Mo\RsSwj/NJ#F;kOZG!5(47Y9UrVn@%Aybul_m6ag$)pf3IEtQ{0W\'K:q1HP&^v8?i`[ ~]|e)'):
        self.chars = chars
        self.keys = {}
        self.genNums()

def encode(s,k,d=False):
    """ Encodes string 's' using string 'k' """
    if k == '': return s ## Makes it easier for Tribble
    elif not len(k) >= 10:
        print('[encd] - key too short')
        return s
    string = [ord(letter) for letter in s]
    ks = KeyString()
    try: key = [ks.keys[letter] for letter in k]
    except:
        print('[encd] - key not valid')
        return s
    length = len(string) - 1
    loc = 0
    for i in xrange(0,length):
        string[i] += key[loc]
        if string[i] > 256: string[i] -= 256
        loc += 1
        if loc == len(key): loc = 0
    loc = 0
    for i in xrange(0,length):        
        temp = 0
        if i + key[loc] > length: temp -= length
        else: temp = key[loc]
        string[i],string[i+temp] = string[i+temp],string[i]
        loc += 1
        if loc == len(key): loc = 0
    if d: print(s,'--->',''.join(chr(item) for item in string))
    try: return ''.join(chr(item) for item in string)
    except: print('Error - ords as follows: %s' % (','.join(str(item) for item in string)))

def decode(s,k,d=False):
    """ Decodes string 's' using string 'k' """
    if k == '': return s ## Makes it easier for Tribble
    if not len(k) >= 10:
        print('[decd] - key too short')
        return s
    string = [ord(letter) for letter in s]
    ks = KeyString()
    try: key = [ks.keys[letter] for letter in k]
    except:
        print('[decd] - key not valid')
        return s
    length = len(string) - 1
    loc = 0
    for i in xrange(0,length):
        loc += 1
        if loc == len(key): loc = 0
    loc -= 1
    if loc == -1: loc = len(key) - 1
    for i in reversed(xrange(0,length)):      
        temp = 0
        if i + key[loc] > length: temp -= length
        else: temp = key[loc]
        string[i],string[i+temp] = string[i+temp],string[i]
        loc -= 1
        if loc == -1: loc = len(key) - 1
    loc = 0
    for i in xrange(0,length):
        string[i] -= key[loc]
        if string[i] < 1: string[i] += 256
        loc += 1
        if loc == len(key): loc = 0
    if d: print(s,'--->',''.join(chr(item) for item in string))
    try: return ''.join(chr(item) for item in string)
    except: print('Error - ords as follows: %s' % (','.join(str(item) for item in string)))

class EncodeDecodeError(Exception):
    def __init__(self,s,k,x,y):
        self.s = s
        self.k = k
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __str__(self):
        return repr('Encode/decode test failed on s=%s k=%s x=%s y=%s' % (self.s,self.k,self.x,self.y))

## The following just tests the encode/decode functions
## and raises an error if it fails
random.seed()

test = True
print('Running encode/decode test...')
for i in xrange(1,1000): ## len(str(i)) <= 5 is the important part
    s = str(random.randint(0,i))
    k = str(random.randint(1000000000,10000000000))
    x = encode(s,k,False)
    y = decode(x,k,False)
    if not y == s: raise EncodeDecodeError(s,k,x,y)
print('Done encode/decode test!')
```

The error is raised somewhere in the encode function.

Here's the file encryption program:

```
import argparse
import sys
from os import path
from functools import partial

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('src',help='source file')
parser.add_argument('out',help='output file')
parser.add_argument('key',help='key to use')
parser.add_argument('-d','--decode',action='store_true',help='decode file')

args = parser.parse_args()

if not path.isfile(args.src):
    print 'Source file "%s" not found' % args.src
    sys.exit(1)

with open(args.src,'rb') as src:
    out = open(args.out,'wb')
    i = 0
    for chunk in iter(partial(src.read,1024),''):
        if not args.decode: x = encode(str(chunk),args.key)
        else: x = decode(str(chunk),args.key)
        out.write(x)
        print '%s kb' % (i)
        i += 1
    out.close()
```

I have imported the file with the encode functions, I just left that import out in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input file contains bytes in the range 0-255, and in **python2** the [chr](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr) function can only return characters within that range:

```
>>> chr(256)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: chr() arg not in range(256)
```

The problem in your code is on this line:

```
    if string[i] > 256: string[i] -= 256
```

which, depending on the input, will occasionally allow `string` to contain `256` (i.e. there's an "off-by-one" error). So, obviously, the way to fix it is simply:

```
    if string[i] > 255: string[i] -= 255
```